# Why does MariaDB-10.2.8 UNHEX() return NULL?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a SQL script that works on MySQL (up to current versions).  I built a copy of MariaDB-10.2.8 from source on a Linux machine and got the database up and running.  However, my SQL script fails, because MariaDB is returning NULL from an UNHEX() call, where it shouldn't.

The call is producing a 20-byte random binary string in a particular format (it's a BitTorrent node ID).  I concatenate some required bytes with some random bytes, with certain bytes being limited to a particular range of values.  These are constructed as a 40-character hex string, which I then run through UNHEX().

The SQL is:

```
    unhex( concat( '414C2',
              hex( 8 + round( rand() * 7 ) ),
              substr( sha( uuid( ) ), 6, 33 ),
              hex( 2 + round( rand( ) ) * 8 ) ) )
```

If you take off the UNHEX() function, you get a 40-character hex string:

```
MariaDB [bt]> select concat('414c2', hex(8+round(rand()*7)),substr(sha(uuid()),6,33),hex(2+round(rand())*8));
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| concat('414c2', hex(8+round(rand()*7)),substr(sha(uuid()),6,33),hex(2+round(rand())*8)) |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 414c29115056f1bd332d4e2e3eb5edd3fc90c0a2                                                |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

but if you UNHEX() it:

```
MariaDB [bt]> select unhex(concat('414c2', hex(8+round(rand()*7)),substr(sha(uuid()),6,33),hex(2+round(rand())*8)));
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| unhex(concat('414c2', hex(8+round(rand()*7)),substr(sha(uuid()),6,33),hex(2+round(rand())*8))) |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NULL                                                                                           |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

By contrast, the same command on a MySQL instance:

```
mysql> select unhex(upper(concat('414c2', hex(8+round(rand()*7)),substr(sha(uuid()),6,33),hex(2+round(rand())*8))));
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| unhex(upper(concat('414c2', hex(8+round(rand()*7)),substr(sha(uuid()),6,33),hex(2+round(rand())*8)))) |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| AL*w??
???r?%??                                                                                            |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

UNHEX() of a 40-character hex string where all the bytes are printable works OK on MariaDB:

```
MariaDB [bt]> select unhex('4142434445464748494a4b4c4d4e4f5051525354');
+---------------------------------------------------+
| unhex('4142434445464748494a4b4c4d4e4f5051525354') |
+---------------------------------------------------+
| ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST                              |
+---------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Any idea why a random hex string wouldn't work?

Comment: Seems to work for me on 10.2.2.  Was the `upper()` necessary?

Comment: No, it was just something I tried along the way.  (My best guess was that I was somehow getting non-hex characters in the string, or uneven number of hex digits, or something that was causing problems with hex->binary conversion.)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug. We've filed a report for this:
https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-13793